# undefined method `schema_cache' for Mongo::Connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise

Trying to *add* Mongodb to an existing app. And I'm getting this error. Not sure how to resolve it let alone understand it.

This comes from me trying to load up the homepage, and Devise is also making a call as so :

```
  1: .grid_24
  2:   .center-stuff
  3:     - if user_signed_in?
  4:       = link_to 'Begin Lesson', esson_path, class: 'button-green'
  5:     - else
  6:       %p Welcome :)
```

**The error**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `schema_cache' for #<Mongo::Connection:0x007f89a7247dd0>):
```

**My user.rb file**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MongoMapper::Document
```

**my initializer**

```
require 'mongo_mapper'
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new
MongoMapper.database = "ai_project-#{Rails.env}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User model should not extend ActiveRecord.

Remove `< ActiveRecord::Base` and you should be good to go

Comment: I had no idea what he meant at first - he means the line "class User < ActiveRecord::Base" should just be "class User" (remove the ActiveRecord::Base" line

Comment: The reason this is happening is because `MongoMapper.connection` is colliding with https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attributes.rb#L93 (`@columns ||= add_user_provided_columns(connection.schema_cache.columns(table_name))`)